# How to get the coordinates of the rotated bounding box

Tags: python, opencv

With python OpenCV I rotate an image that already has bounding boxes. I do this using the `getRotationMatrix2D` function. How can I use this to calculate the new coordinates of the bounding box?

Here is my sourcecode:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

def rotateImage(image, angle, bboxes):
    center=tuple(np.array(image.shape[0:2])/2)
    rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center,angle,1.0)
    return cv2.warpAffine(image, rot_mat, image.shape[0:2],flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)


img = cv2.imread('input.jpg')
img = img[:,:,::-1]

img_new = rotateImage(img, 5.0, [(0,0,50,50)])

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img),plt.title('Input')
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(img_new),plt.title('Output')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You can apply the same transformation to the bounding points coordinates via cv2.transform()

Comment: cv2.perspectiveTransform should be useful, although it did not work for my current implementation yet.